Adding submenu item in LWR Experience Site's navigation menu
I am working on an LWR experience cloud site. While creating a new navigation menu, I am unable to add sub menu items. Please find the below image, I want to add "New Menu Item" under "Page 1".


You need to first create a Menu Label as "Page 1" in the menu. For that, you need to select the Type as "Menu Label". Then create a new menu that you want as a sub-menu and drag the menu under the previously created menu label.

See the this: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/28170844?key=4fedb09a280fb9bf9c97e88cbb829bcf

Thanks it worked
